# Composer update dependencies Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Is it okay to update the dependencies of a magento store using command composer update? The store is functional and running on magento 2.3 at the moment.

Comment: What do you want to update to? Magento 2.3 is the latest version

Comment: Yes I understand it is latest version. When I did composer update on a test server, It did update few dependencies like zend framework updated from 2.8.2 to 2.8.3 and elastic search updated to 5.4 and so on.